# Cisco 871 Router VLAN Ideas

Tags: vlan

I am trying to configure 2 VLANS on my Cisco 871 router. VLAN 10 & VLAN 20.

VLAN 10 is for my VoIP.

VLAN 20 is for my Data.

My physical connection is this: ISP > Cisco 871 > Unmanaged Switch > All Devices

So I have My ISP connected to FastEthernet 4 & I have my Unmanaged Switch connected to FastEthernet 1 .. All my network devices are connected to that unmanaged switch.

What I want to do is tag all my cisco SPA IP phones with vlan 10. And have that port Fe1 do some sort of subinterface.

I'm not sure how that would work...

Can Anyone tell me what I'm trying to do is possible?

& If so. How?

Comment: An unmanaged switch by definition, can't do VLANs.  How would the IP Phones be placed into that VLAN?

Comment: Well I would tag the packets coming from the IP phones with the VLAN ID.. There is an option to do so in the IP Phones.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The switch as mentioned earlier has to be vlan aware, and then you would configure the connection to the router as a trunk port, add both vlans to that switch and encapsulate them with 802.1q, make the data traffic native for vlan 20, and mark the phone traffic with vlan id 10, you can buy a cheap Cisco 2950 if bandwidth does not need to be more then 100mbps, if your internet speed is slower you may also want to configure QOS with a service policy or such.